# Importing a file in javascript always adds up localhost in front of the path

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am writing a project using ionic and I try to import a local JSON-file.

But no matter how I try to do it let it be

```
this.http.get('../assets/data/MyList.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => 
  {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

or

```
var txt = '';
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
    txt = xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET","/absolute/path/to/MyList.json",true);
    xmlhttp.send();

console.log(txt);
```

Every time I start up my project and try to open the file, the same error comes on:

> http://localhost:8100/absolute/path/to/MyList.json" 404 (Not Found)

What am I doing wrong? Why does it always include `localhost`?

Comment: Because you are making a HTTP request, not getting the file from the File System of the device

Comment: You can't just access the local file system, and for good and obvious security related reasons. It's just doesn't work that way

Comment: Okay, get that.. So there is no way for me to import a local JSON to my object?

Comment: You need to place that file in the public directory, so if for example localhost direct to `public_html`, and you place it there, it will be accessible from `http://localhost:8100/myList.json` (Using a simple GET request). This is one way to do it

Comment: @Doctor use `const json = require(path)`, `import json from path`, or `const json = await import(path)` as appropriate